# In the US, how closely are people who die in a fire investigated?

Tags: law, crime, death

Let's say a house burns down and there's a body in the house.  The body is badly damaged but roughly matches the sole inhabitant of the house.  How much effort is typically required to ensure the body is the obvious suspect?  Is it the law that people check dental records every time or might that be overlooked if the general vitals (height, weight, gender) of the body match expectations?

Comment: This isn't really on topic, since it is more about medical or police procedures in the real world. We try to stay away from such questions or else this site would be just a collection of random trivia. So I'm voting to close as off-topic. On the other hand, finding a dead body in the US means the police must start suspecting murder; or arson in this case. If the police arrive at the scene, they will absolutely work with the coroner to provide a positive identification of the body. Any large department will have strict rules; a more rural fire with a smaller sheriff's department, perhaps not.

Comment: You might ask this at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/), but it might be off-topic for them, too (as it's about procedure and not strictly the law).

Comment: Perhaps this should be reframed as a [tag:reality-check]?  And keep in mind that the vast majority of fires are *not* arson -- cooking fires are all-too-common, and so are malfunctions in electrical systems or appliances, careless candle usage, and so on...

Comment: Speaking as someone who has investigated deaths in fires, the *first* thing done is to check to see if the fire was used to cover up a homicide and that the victim is who it's supposed to be given the situation described.